# How to print missing rows in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

How to print the misisng rows from a table from expected set of values.

I am expecting the values A, B, C, D, E to be in the below employee table, if any of the value is missing, how to get the misisng record.

```
EMP_NAME     STATUS
--------    --------
A            VALID
B            VALID
D            VALID
```

In the above table C & E are missing. How can I write a sql to print that C & E are missing rows from the table

Comment: Do you have another table that contains all expected values? If not that would be a good first start. Then it's just a matter of a LEFT OUTER JOIN to this table with condition `WHERE thistable.Emp_Name IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

For a sample table

```
SQL> select * from test;

EMP_NAME   STATUS
---------- ------
A          VALID
B          VALID
C          VALID
```

you have to know *which* employees are missing. I hope you have a table that contains the full list; I created a CTE that serves that purpose, having only the first 5 letters of English alphabet (I presume you used *dummy* names, didn't you?). Then you'd outer join it to table you already have. Something like this:

```
SQL> with all_emps as
  2    (select chr(65 + level - 1) emp_name
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 5
  5    )
  6  select a.emp_name,
  7         nvl(t.status, 'Unknown') status
  8  from all_emps a left join test t on t.emp_name = a.emp_name
  9  order by a.emp_name;

EMP_NAME   STATUS
---------- -------
A          VALID
B          VALID
C          VALID
D          Unknown
E          Unknown

SQL>
```

---

As it seems that you do know which employees you have, then - by modifying above *dummy* query - you'd have

```
SQL> select * from test;

EMP_NAME   STATUS
---------- ----------
CAM        VALID
POOD       VALID
HAM        VALID

SQL> with all_emps (emp_name) as
  2    (select 'CAM'  from dual union all
  3     select 'POOD' from dual union all
  4     select 'HAM'  from dual union all
  5     select 'HAL'  from dual union all
  6     select 'NIL'  from dual
  7    )
  8  select a.emp_name,
  9         nvl(t.status, 'Unknown') status
 10  from all_emps a left join test t on t.emp_name = a.emp_name
 11  order by a.emp_name;

EMP_NAME   STATUS
---------- ----------
CAM        VALID
HAL        Unknown
HAM        VALID
NIL        Unknown
POOD       VALID

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have used dummy names and I dont have an exisiting table that contains full list. Is there any other way to write the sql statement if we know the employee names but dont exist in  a table? For eg: I know that CAM,POOD,HAM,HAL,NIL needs to be in the table but I only have CAM,POOD,HAM andmissing HAL & NIL

Comment: @binganapedia - will you know those names before you write your query, or will you only know them when your run it? (Possibly different lists of "required names" at different times?) If it's the latter, where will the "required names" come from?

Comment: I will know them before I run it, its constant values and there is no change in that names, say for eg I expect that only CAM,POOD,HAM,HAL,NIL  needs to be in the table. If its missing any of the values the sql should print the missing names

Comment: Then create the "all_emps" table (pseudo-table) in the `with` clause. Littlefoot can edit his answer to show you how.

Comment: Edited; have a look.